# Configure same PMD ruleset for eclipse-pmd as gradle PMD uses - Which ruleset is used for net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I have PMD checks in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
apply plugin: "pmd"

dependencies {
  pmd "net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-java:5.5.+"
}
/*** PMD ***/

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    excludes = ["**/gen/*"]
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

**Which ruleset is used here?**

I would like to configure the same ruleset for the eclipse PMD plugin (Project Properties -> PMD - Add). 
Ideally eclipse project is configured by gradle to have the correct settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default config for Gradle is using [`java-basic`](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/index.html#Basic) ([source](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension:ruleSets))

However, this is a very conservative approach that takes little advantage of all PMD has to offer.

My personal advice as a PMD maintainer is that you:

1. Review all rules available at https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/index.html
2. [Create your own ruleset](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html) including those rules you agreed with, with all extra properties you may want to change from defaults.

Both Gradle and the PMD Eclipse plugin can load rules from a ruleset on file, making it easy to keep both of them in sync at all times.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I extended the rulesets and added it to my gradle `pmd {
 ruleSetFiles = files("${rootProject.projectDir}/config/pmd/ruleset.xml")`

Comment: @timguy amazing! Also of note, 5.5.x is a very old version of PMD. Latest release is 5.8.1 (6.0.0 coming out soon). You should consider updating, and to do so, not define the dependency directly, but use `pmd { toolVersion = '5.8.1' }` since PMD is actually split over a couple of different jars